# Bad practice to call base methods in derived constructors?

Tags: c++, oop, class, methods, constructor

I was just wondering on the most efficient way of setting inherited members was and if the following code is alright to use:

This is the declaration of the base class:

```
class cEntity{
private:
    int X, Y;
    int Height, Width;
public:
    cEntity();
    cEntity(int x,int y,int h,int w);
    ~cEntity();

    void setX(int x){X=x;};
    void setY(int y){Y=y;};
    void setCoords(int x, int y){X=x;Y=y;};

    void setHeight(int h){Height = h;};
    void setWidth(int w){Width = w;};
    void setArea(int h, int w){Height=h;Width=w;};

    int getX(){return X;};
    int getY(){return Y;};
    //void getXY(int,int);

    int getHeight(){return Height;};
    int getWidth(){return Width;};
    //void getArea(int,int);
};
```

and here is the constructor of the derived class:

```
cOrganism::cOrganism () {
    setCoords(0,0);
    setArea(0,0);
    Name = "UNKNOWN";
    Health = 100;
    MaxHealth = 100;
    HealthHiRange =100;
    HealthLoRange = 100;
};
```

So. Is is alright to call the `setCoords()` and `setArea()` in the derived class' constructor?

Comment: No it is not bad practice. What is bad practice is [calling virtual methods from your derived constructor][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/496440/c-virtual-function-from-constructor

Comment: @carleeto: calling virtual methods from a constructor is perfectly all right in C++. it is dangerous in Java. in C++ it is safe and well-defined in a correct program.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's alright, but you can do much better by calling the base constructor:

```
cOrganism::cOrganism() : cEntity(0, 0, 0, 0) {
  // other stuff
}
```

In fact, you should initialize your new, derived members the same way:

```
cOrganism::cOrganism()
: cEntity(0, 0, 0, 0),
  Name("UNKNOWN"),
  Health(100),
  ...
{
}
```

(You might also want to read up a bit on general C++ class design: If you expose getters and setters to all your private variables, something isn't quite right. A class is supposed to *encapsulate* a model, while you're doing essentially the opposite. But that's not a technical error.)

Comment: And how do I set the base constructors arguments in this situation: `cOrganism::cOrganism() : cEntity(0, 0, 0, 0)` As in, what would the syntax look like when creating an object in my code?

Comment: What do you mean? You're calling the four-argument version of the base constructor, which I assume would set `X`, `Y`, `Height` and `Width`. You have to implement *that* constructor correctly as well, of course. You create a derived object just with the default constructor: `cOrganism jim;`

Comment: Any argument you want to pass to a constructor has to be a parameter of that constructor...

Comment: I understand but when i create an object like this: `cOrganism org3(h, mh, hh, lh, n);` how would i set the base constructor's variables? How does the syntax change?

Comment: Oh. Just add a proper constructor for the derived class: `cOrganism(int a, int b, int c, int d, std::string name) : cEntity(a, b, c, d), Name(name), Health(50) { }`

Answer (score 1):

Much better to call it like this:

```
cOrganism::cOrganism () : cEntity(0,0,0,0) {
  Name = "UNKNOWN";
  Health = 100;
  MaxHealth = 100;
  HealthHiRange =100;
  HealthLoRange = 100;
}
```

Or even better:

```
cOrganism::cOrganism ()
 : cEntity(0,0,0,0), Name("UNKNOWN"), Health(100), 
   MaxHealth(100), HealthHiRange(100), HealthLoRange(100)
{}
```

That way the base class members are set as the base class implementation is constructed.

Comment: It seems I am always one step behind @Kerrek SB...Curse you! :)

Answer (score 0):

If the default constructor of the base class already intializes it to good values you don't have to do it all.

Otherwise the good solution is something like below.

```
class A
{
int x;
public:
    A( int xin) :x(xin) {}
};


class B : public A
{
int y;
public:
    B( int xin , int yin ) :A(xin) , y(yin) {}
};
```

Notice **A(xin)** in B constructor. This will called pass xin to the A constructor.

If you have something like integers it doesn't really matter what you do. But if A::X was actually a heavy weight object. With your approach A::x will be constructed once with default constructor and then assigned again when setCoords() is called from derived class constructor. My solution will ensure *A::x** is only constructed once and that too with all the right value of its parameters.

[More details here](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/114-constructors-and-initialization-of-derived-classes/)