# Binding within Constructors within Constructors

Tags: c++, oop, binding, constructor, dynamic-binding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calling virtual functions inside constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962132/calling-virtual-functions-inside-constructors)

in C++, An object of class B derived from class A, in C++ the c’tor of A is invoked before the c’tor of B , why ?
And what happens if A’s C’tor invokes a virtual function? does it invoke A's virtual function of B's ?

Comment: What happens with virtuals: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/496440/c-virtual-function-from-constructor

Comment: Why don't you try and see what happens?

Answer (score 0):

Most of your questions, if not all, are covered by the C++ FAQ.

E.g. see the FAQ ["When my base class's constructor calls a virtual function on its this object, why doesn't my derived class's override of that virtual function get invoked?"](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/strange-inheritance.html#faq-23.5).

It is always a good idea to read the FAQ before asking.