# What happens when an asynchronous callback calls a virtual function, while base class constructor is not returned yet?

Tags: c++, constructor, callback, virtual, asynccallback

I have the following scenario:

```
class Caller{
public:
  Caller()               {...}
  void register(Base* b) {...}
  void callBase() { b->virt()}
};

class Base {
public:
  Base(Caller c)      { println("Base::Base()");  c.register(this); sleep(30); }
  virtual void virt() { println("Base::virt()"); }
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
  Derived()           { println("Derived::Derived()"); }
  virtual void virt() { println("Derived::virt()"); }
};
```

I know normally if someone calls virt on the derived class Derived::virt() will be called. But here, if the function callBase is called while Base is sleeping in the parent constructor, which function will be called? Base::virt() or Derived::virt()?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ virtual function from constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/496440/c-virtual-function-from-constructor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [C++ Lite FAQ 23.5](http://www.parashift.com/c%2B%2B-faq-lite/calling-virtuals-from-ctors.html), `Base::virt()` will be called.

Anyway, it's really not something you want to do - if your object is used by another thread without proper initialization, you can encounter all sorts of nasty race conditions. For example, what would happen if the second thread called `virt` *exactly when the vtable is set*? Who's to guarantee that setting the vtable during object construction is an atomic operation?

You should design your code in such a way that your objects aren't used before they're fully initialized.

Comment: You are right. I figured the cause of the crash was the race condition, when child constructor is not finished (fields were not created yet), while the callback calls the child virt() function and it tries to use the fields.

Answer (score 3):

It would call `Base::virt`. Until the base class constructor has finished, virtual functions are dispatched as if the dynamic type were `Base`.

(Although technically you'd have undefined behaviour if another thread accessed the object without proper synchronisation. And the program wouldn't compile since `register` is a keyword.)

Answer (score 1):

While in the Constructor or Destructor for `Base`, the class acts in nearly every way as if it was a `Base`.
That means the `Base`-implementation for any called virtual function is used.

If there is none (which is possible, because `Base` may declare it as pure virtual, making `Base`an abstract class), you get [**Undefined Behavior**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior), so everything can happen.
Often seen behaviors for this case include crashing on invalid access, deliberately aborting with an error and calling some derived classes override.

If the call is concurrently (multithreading/signals), the standard says you go straight to **UB**.

Java, C# and the like have completely different rules there, so examine this for each new language in isolation.

Aside: Using `register` as a name in C++ is ill-advised. It is not allowed, because it is a defunct (i.e. no effect at all) storage-class keyword.